# Infima in the Rudin-Keisler ordering

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, order-theory, lattice-theory, ultrafilters

Let $\text{NPU}(\omega)$ be the set of non-principal [ultafilters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrafilter) on $\omega$. The *Rudin-Keisler preorder* on $\text{NPU}(\omega)$ is defined by
$${\cal U} \leq_{RK} {\cal V} :\Leftrightarrow (\exists f:\omega\to\omega)(\forall U\in{\cal U}) f^{-1}(U)\in {\cal V} .$$

It is easy to see that $\leq_{RK}$ is reflexive and transitive, but not anti-symmetric. Set ${\cal U}\simeq_{RK} {\cal V}$ if ${\cal U}\leq_{RK}{\cal V}$ and ${\cal V}\leq_{RK}{\cal U}$. So $\text{NPU}(\omega)/\simeq_{RK}$ is a poset with the Rudin-Keisler order applied to equivalence classes.

It is [known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrafilter#Ultrafilters_on_.E2.84.98.28.CF.89.29) that if ${\cal R}$ is a minimal element of  [Ramsey ultrafilter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrafilter#Ultrafilters_on_.E2.84.98.28.CF.89.29), then $[{\cal R}]_{\simeq_{RK}}$ is a minimal element of $\text{NPU}(\omega)/\simeq_{RK}$.

**Question.** Suppose ${\cal U, V}\in \text{NPU}(\omega)$ are non-Ramsey , do $[{\cal U}]_{\simeq_{RK}}, [{\cal V}]_{\simeq_{RK}}$ have an infimum in $\text{NPU}(\omega)/\simeq_{RK}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This part only shows the existence of lower bounds, which is not the point. See edit.**
<strike>This is consistently true for example when the near coherence principle of ultrafilters holds. It says, for any two non-principal ultrafilters $U, V$ there exists a finite-to-one $f: \omega\to \omega$ such that $f(U)=f(V)$. Since $f$ is finite-to-one, it makes sure $f(U)=f(V)$ is not principal.</strike>

**Edit:** the answer is consistently no. Suppose there exist two non-isomorphic Ramsey ultrafilters $U, V$, then we claim $U\cdot V$ and $V\cdot U$ do not have an infimum. This follows from the following facts

1. $U\cdot V, V\cdot U$ are neither P-point nor Q-point
2. $U\cdot V \simeq V\cdot U$ implies $U\simeq V$
3. The only elements that are potentially RK below $U\cdot V$ are $V\cdot U$, $U$, $V$ (or the principal ultrafilters)
4. So the common non-principal lower bounds for $U\cdot V, V\cdot U$ are $U, V$. But they are incomparable.

All of these can be found in Blass' thesis.

Comment: Does NCF actually give you an infimum, or just the existence of lower bounds?  This isn't immediately clear to me.

Comment: I don't think it does. that answer is not right to the point as I didn't finish reading the question. I think the answer is no if there are two non-isomorphic selective ultrafilters.

Comment: Thanks and +1Jing Zhang! Can you elaborate on the non-isomorphic selective ultrafilters?

Comment: @DominicvanderZypen: I think you can try the following to classify the ultrafilters below $U\cdot V$ (similarly $V\cdot U$): suppose $W\leq_{RK} U\cdot V$, let $f: \omega\times \omega\to \omega$ be the witness. Then you can cook up two functions $g: \omega\to \omega$ such that $g(n)=k$ iff $\{m: f(n,m)=k\}\in V$. Similary $h$ reversing the role of $U$ and $V$. By Ramsey, there are 4 cases to consider: g is constant on a $U$-large set, or 1-1 and similarly for $h$. This might help.

Comment: Thanks @JingZhang, it makes sense. Maybe you can put this comment into your answer, I am tipping towards accepting it now because I think I can work out the details

Comment: OK I think I'm comfortable enough to work it out. Thanks for your help @JingZhang!